# Unable to perform update on MongoDB record

Tags: mongodb

After trying for almost 2 hours , i am posting this question

```
$.ajax( {
 type: "POST" ,
 url: "http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/stocks/?q={symbol:"+symbol+"}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 data: JSON.stringify( { "$set" : { 'tbq' : "3" } } ),
dataType: "json"
 } );
```

A sample inside mongodb

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("537148b99aae10a52d6b5dbe"),
        "symbol" : "KIYT",
        "tbq" : "566"

}
```

Could anybody please tel me why the update isn't working ??

I was following this link http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#update-documents

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a PUT as opposed to a POST, as POST will attempt to add a new item to Mongo. You also need to give the _id of the item that you're trying to update. For instance;

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT" ,
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/stocks/?q={"_id":537148b99aae10a52d6b5dbe}',
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify( { "$set" : { 'tbq' : "3" } } ),
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: If i use PUT instead of POST , i am getting in my mongodb console [websvr] don't know how to handle a [PUT]

Comment: Apologies I had not realised that you were attempting to do this on a local installation (I should have looking at the URL!) The REST API for mongolabs allows inserting and updating, however the API for mongod does not. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#rest-api